# Spyder Python Shortcut to Select All Text Above Current Line

Tags: python, spyder

Let's say I'm on line 500 in spyder, and I want to run everything from that line and above (lines 1-500), is there a shortcut to select the lines quickly. Right not I'm highlighting the lines and scrolling up and using shift and up arrow but both of them take some time to scroll. Is there a faster way to select, similar to select all but only for the specific lines 1-500?

Comment: `CTRL`-`Shift`-`Home` works for me on Windows. Although it has the possibly undesired side effect of scrolling up to top of file.

Comment: @thesilkworm awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) The easiest way to do what you want is by creating code cells. These are sections in your file separated by comments of the form `# %%`, which can be run independently by placing the cursor inside them and pressing the shortcuts `Ctrl+Enter` (run cell) and `Shift+Enter` (run cell and and advance to the next one).

Please refer to [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/editor.html#defining-code-cells) for more details.

Comment: Great! Glad you find them useful.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old I know, but I found out that CTRL-Shift-Home doesn't work for me.
I have to use CTRL-Alt-Shift-Home to select everything above the line or -End for everything below.
This is for Windows 7 and Spider 3.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is interested in deleting all the lines, and only find this question after searching, the easy way would be using

`'''`

for all the codes between the two lines, and then use the triangle on the left to suppress, so you could delete in one go.